# is $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\cap L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$ closed in $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ bounded, open, connected and Lip. domain. Is $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\cap L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$  closed in $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$? i.e., with the norm of $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$. Is important for me because if $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\cap L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$ is closed, it is a reflexive Banach space and every bounded sequence contains a subsequence which is weakly convergent.

Comment: If you have a  subset $M\subset L^\infty$ that is closed with respect to pointwise a.e. convergence then $H^1\cap M$ is closed in $H^1$: convergence in $H^1$ implies a.e. convergence of a subsequence...

Comment: @daw. If we consider $M=\left\{ \sigma\in L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)\left|\,\sigma\left(x\right)\geq\sigma_{-},\:a.e\right.\right\}$ , where $\sigma_{-}$ is a positive constant, $M$ is closed in $L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$. Then $N=M\cap H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ is closed in $H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$...

Comment: Let be $\left(\sigma_{k}\right)_{k}\subset N$ such that $\sigma_{k}\rightarrow\sigma\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$. So, exists a subsequence $\left(\sigma_{k_{j}}\right)_{j}$ such that $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\sigma_{k_{j}}\left(x\right)=\sigma\left(x\right)$ a.e. Then $\sigma\left(x\right)\geq\sigma_{-}$ a.e. Therefore, N is closed. Is this correct?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: **Thanks** @daw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Due to your given geometric conditions we have $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$, and $C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ is a subset of $H^1(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$. However, if $d\geq 2$, there exists some $f\in H^1\setminus L^\infty$, so $H^1(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ is a proper subset of $H^1(\Omega)$, whose closure is $H^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Then $\overline{H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\cap L^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)} = H^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ if $2\leq d$. Thanks so much @Peter.